# How to change in predifine method of java class

Tags: java

I want to change in predefined method of ArrayList class. suppose if we add any element to arraylist . simultaneously system will print "value is added in arraylist" . is it possible to do changes on add() of ArrayList class.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation composition is usually preferred over inheritance (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

For example, if you follow the approach of extending the `ArrayList` class, do you also want your logic invoked when `add(int index, E element)` is called.  What about `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`.  What if a new add method is added in a subsequent version of Java?

Instead, consider implementing your own `List`.  Internally it would delegated operations to an `ArrayList`, but you are forced to think about how to handle each type of addition.

Comment: I agree. I would suggest to use a wrapper design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class foo extends ArrayList<Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Object e) {
    // print your stuff here
    return super.add(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about method `overriding` ??

```
public class MyArrayLIst  extends ArrayList<ClassObj>{

   @Override
   public void add(ClassObj obj) {
      //sysout
      return super.add(obj);

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your own overridden add method which calls add method of ArrayList and prints what you want as well. must be done with inheriting the class.